# how to run Select and where statement in django

Tags: django

How to Select and Put Where Condition in Django? And how to print in `view.py`?

I am trying like this but not works.

```
check2 = Project_Time_Status.objects.filter(project_id=project_id).filter(finishing_time__isnull=True).all()
if check2:
    for unit in check2:
        print (unit.project_id)

select * from Project_Time_Status where project_id = projectid AND finishing_time != null
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: change the query to this `check2 = Project_Time_Status.objects.filter(project_id=project_id, finishing_time__isnull=True)` print check2 and see what you get first, then you can debug further.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter the details based on some condition you can use `filter()` method.

```
check2 = Project_Time_Status.objects.filter(project_id=project_id,finishing_time__isnull=True)
```

This would be same as:

```
select * from Project_Time_Status where project_id = projectid AND finishing_time != null
```

Then you can print the results like this:

```
for record in check2:
    print(record)
```